# Sending the text from Arduino to iphone using bluetooth, i can not take a character.value

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, arduino

Purpose : Arduino sends a sensor value to iphone application.

Problem:
I made a BlueTooth application which could connect with Arduino. 
I successed very sometimes like [Fig 4].
But I could not take a string from arduino. 
I could get just “<00>” or clear space.

What I have to revise my application?
I have to change Arduino first? Or my ios source code?

[Fig 1] is Arduino Bluetooth source code => (Bluetooth is bluetooth 4.0)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int blueTx = 6; 
int blueRx = 7; 

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(blueRx,blueTx); //connect HC-10 TX, RX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("hello world");      
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("BTSerial begin");
}

void loop() {
  while(BTSerial.available())
  {

    BTSerial.println("hello world");
    BTSerial.write("BTSerial is open!");
  }
}
```

[Fig 2] is Xcode Log

```
2015-09-24 15:58:52.822 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] STATE - Power On
2015-09-24 15:58:52.822 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] SCAN - Scanning
2015-09-24 15:58:52.873 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] DISCOVER - Discover : <CBPeripheral: 0x135537f00, identifier = B4A88537-AF01-B403-AA32-F2C84464CFE6, name = HMSoft, state = disconnected>
2015-09-24 15:58:52.873 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] DISCOVER - Connecting to peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x135537f00, identifier = B4A88537-AF01-B403-AA32-F2C84464CFE6, name = HMSoft, state = connecting>
2015-09-24 15:58:53.015 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] CONNECT - To HMSoft
2015-09-24 15:58:53.016 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] CONNECT - Scanning stoped
2015-09-24 15:58:53.301 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] DISCOVER_SERVICE - Service : <CBService: 0x13556ae90, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFE0>
2015-09-24 15:58:53.421 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] DISCOVER_CHAR - Characteristic : <CBCharacteristic: 0x135673ce0, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = (null), notifying = NO>
2015-09-24 15:58:53.481 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] UPDATE_VALUE - start
2015-09-24 15:58:53.481 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData : 
2015-09-24 15:58:53.481 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] UPDATA_VALUE - data : <00>
2015-09-24 15:58:53.691 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] NOTIFY - Notification start
2015-09-24 15:58:53.691 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] NOTIFY - Notification began on <CBCharacteristic: 0x135673ce0, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = <00>, notifying = YES>
2015-09-24 15:58:53.691 Arduino_BLE test1[1727:734383] NOTIFY - stringFromData :
```

[Fig 3] is what I wrote source code for Bluetooth network.

```
//DISCOVER CHAR
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {NSLog(@"DISCOVER_CHAR - Error");return;}

    for (CBCharacteristic * characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"DISCOVER_CHAR - Characteristic : %@",characteristic);
        [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
}

//INTERACT
//READ
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
            error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"UPDATE_VALUE - start");
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData : %@", stringFromData);

    [_data appendData:characteristic.value];
    NSLog(@"UPDATA_VALUE - data : %@",_data);
}
```

[Fig 4] is what I Succeed before. But ….. I can not do it again

```
UPDATA_VALUE - start
UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData :
UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData :<00>
UPDATA_VALUE - start    
UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData :hello world

BTSeria
UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData:<0068656c 6c6f2077 6f726c64 0d0a4254 53657269 61>
UPDATA_VALUE - start
UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData :l begin

UPDATA_VALUE - stringFromData :<0068656c 6c6f2077 6f726c64 0d0a4254 53657269 616c2062 6567696e 0d0a>
```

Comment: Why are you using hardware serial pins as software serial pins? The pins 0 and 1 are for hardware UART. Use some other IOs for software UART.

Comment: Thank you your advice!! I changed it.!  pin0  -> pin6 and pin1->7. but the probelm is not solved.

Comment: Are you using HC-05? What is the baud rate that you are using?

Comment: No. I read the article which was that HC-05 or 06 can not connect to iphone. so i used bluetooth 4.0 module. Actually i don't know about the baud rate. Can you give me a explanation about baud rate? how can i control a baud rate in source code. and what is it meaning to this tech.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your current code:

```
BTSerial.begin(9600);
```

This syntax suggests that you are using 9600 baud rate. First you need to figure out that what is the baud rate at which your device accepts data. 
If you dont know the baud rate, you could try with different standard baudrates like 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400 etc. 
You can refer to the data sheet of your bluetooth module for this information.

Comment: Thank you Meet Desai. I tried to change baud rate of arduino. Both 9600 and 19200 were working to iphone bluetooth network. but iphone can not take a message from Arduino through BTSerial.println("hello world"). In this moment, i have a question. If i want to send the message continuously, then i will need more code in arduino?

Comment: Dont try a full string directly. First try sending one character. If one character is a success then you may go ahead with strings. I didnt understand your question about sending message continuously.

Comment: Meet Desai.!! thanky you. I changed things one by one. Finally, I got the message from arduino. The problem is "Value format" of sensorValue in Arduino. I just changed the format of value of sensorValue from "int" to "byte" . that is work! I solve it!!!! Thank you again for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Meet Desai.!! thank you. I changed things one by one. Finally, I got the message from arduino. The problem is "Value format" of sensorValue in Arduino. I just changed the format of value of sensorValue from "`int`" to "`byte`" . that is work! I solve it!!!! Thank you again for your attention.